# Remove class added with hover and animationend on mouseout

Tags: javascript, html, css, transitionend

I have tried out the `transitionend` and `animationend` to change my css after a `transition` or `keyframes` animation ends. I made an example with both variants and they worked as expected: I can `toggle` a `class`, when a `transition` or animation ends. On hover, I start the transition/animation and in `JavaScript` I toggle a class, which changes the `background-color`, after the transition/animation changes.

The only difference is, that when I do the mouseout and the div goes back to the original state, with `transition` and transitionend, the class will be removed and the original `background-color` is visible. For `keyframes` animations and `animationend`, the class and `background-color` stay, also when I do the mouseout. How can I get the same behavoir for the `animationend` like the `transition`?

```js
var boxTransition = document.getElementById("transition");
var boxAnimation = document.getElementById("animation");

/* add class after transition ends */
boxTransition.addEventListener("transitionend", changeBackground);

/* add class after keyframes animation ends */
boxAnimation.addEventListener("animationend", changeBackground);

function changeBackground() {
  this.classList.toggle("box--end");
}
```

```css
.box {
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  width: 100px;
}

.box--transition {
  background-color: lightcoral;
  transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.box--transition:hover {
  width: 300px;
}

.box--animation {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.box--animation:hover {
  animation: animateWidth 0.5s ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.box--end {
  background-color: gray;
}

@keyframes animateWidth {
  from {
    width: 100px;
  }
  to {
    width: 300px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="transition" class="box box--transition"></div>
<div id="animation" class="box box--animation"></div>
```

Comment: You want the original colour to stay once the `mouseout` event happens ?

Comment: @Towkir Yes, because transitionend is smart enough to toggle the class, but animationend not, so I'm asking myself is it possible to make the same behavoir for animationend without additional hack. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should note that animation and transition are not the same, Thus event handling here is a bit trikcy.

I am going to explain what happens on both of them.

Transition: It's just the animating part of an element's changing property.
Example, it could be width or height or color. It is assigned on `:hover` usually.
Thus, it does not wait for animation if a user takes the mouse out of the element before the transition completes.

On the other hand,

Animation: is a complete set of transition and does not care about the user's `mouseout`  event, once starts, it ends on it's own.

So, here is what you can do. As you assigned the toggle on `transitionend` it's okay because whenever the user takes the mouse out, transition completes and then the event triggers, but for animation, you should take care of them explicitly.

What I did is, (assuming user will keep the mouse on the element for a few second) added the class once animation has ended (like `transitionend`) then removed the class once the user takes the mouse out of the element.

Not exactly this is what you should do, but you can now get an idea on what to do and when.

Demo:

```js
var boxTransition = document.getElementById("transition");
var boxAnimation = document.getElementById("animation");

/* add class after transition ends */
boxTransition.addEventListener("transitionend", changeBackground);

/* add class after keyframes animation ends */
boxAnimation.addEventListener("animationend", greyOnStart);
boxAnimation.addEventListener("mouseout", revertOnEnd);

function changeBackground() {
  this.classList.toggle("box--end");
}

function greyOnStart(){
  this.classList.add('box--end');
}

function revertOnEnd(){
  this.classList.remove('box--end');
}
```

```css
.box {
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  width: 100px;
}

.box--transition {
  background-color: lightcoral;
  transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.box--transition:hover {
  width: 300px;
}

.box--animation {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.box--animation:hover {
  animation: animateWidth 0.5s ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.box--end {
  background-color: gray;
}

@keyframes animateWidth {
  from {
    width: 100px;
  }
  to {
    width: 300px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="transition" class="box box--transition"></div>
<div id="animation" class="box box--animation"></div>
```

Comment: Nice one thanks. I know, that I can trigger the mouseoute and remove it by myself, I was just askin myselft if animationend also can toggle it with hover/mouseout without additional code like transitionend. So this seems not to work and the explanation from your side is clear. Still a nice solution to get this work! An interessting topic. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I can see 2 options for you.
First one is to call `changeBackground` on `boxAnimation.onMouseOut()`:

```
boxAnimation.addEventListener("mouseout", changeBackground);
```

That will change background immediately.
Second is to set animation for `.box--animation` without hover:

```
@keyframes animateWidth2 {
  from {
    width: 300px;
  }
  to {
    width: 100px;
  }
}
.box--animation {
  animation: animateWidth2 0.5s ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

That will work like transition, but will happen on start too.
To prevent this happen from start you can add `.box--hovered` class to `.box` in `changeBackground()` and add animation to `.box--animation.box--hovered` instead of just `.box--animation`.
[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/Jakupov/pzv8jest/1/) for second variant.